# PySpark repartition according to a specific column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am looking how to repartition (in PySpark) a dataset so that all rows that have the same ID in a specified column move to the same partition. In fact, I have to run in each partition a program which computes a single value for all rows having the same ID.

I have a dataframe (df) built from a HIVE QL query (with lets say contains 10000 distinct IDs).
I tried :

```
df = df.repartition("My_Column_Name")
```

By default I get 200 partitions, but always I obtain 199 IDs for which I got duplicated computed values when I run the program.

I looked on the web, and some people recommended to define a custom partitioner to use with `repartition` method, but I wasn't able to find how to do that in Python.

Is there a way to do this repartition correctly?

Comment: Let me recommend you to rephrase the question. 

I guess that what you want to achieve is to repartition your DataFrame into the same number of partitions as the amount of different ID's the DataFrame contains. In this particular case, you want 1000 partitions each of those containing a single ID. Am I correct?

The reason why you are trying to achieve this is not clear on your question, but it suggest that you have some misconception about what is the "normal" way of working with Spark.

Comment: If you need to run code that is relevant for some rows with the same Id simply groupByKey (Or reduceByKey) that id and preform the needed logic. But do not mix the "logic" part of what you want to do with the "quality of execution" part. The number of partitions is more relevant to the latter and should be chosen based on the number of cores you have on your cluster.

Comment: I want only to have ALL rows with the same IDs moved to the same partition. No problem if a partition contains several groups of rows with distinct IDs. 1000 was just an example, the number of different IDs can be very high. So, partitionning a DF to number of different IDs partitions should not lead to good performances.

I need that because I run a function (which cannot be implemented using basic Spark transformation functions) using RDD mapPartition method. This function produces one result per distinct ID, this is why I need to have all rows with the same ID in the same partition.

Answer (score 0):

I want only to have ALL rows with the same IDs moved to the same partition. No problem if a partition contains several groups of rows with distinct IDs. 1000 was just an example, the number of different IDs can be very high. So, partitionning a DF to number of different IDs partitions should not lead to good performances. I need that because I run a function (which cannot be implemented using basic Spark transformation functions) using RDD mapPartition method. This function produces one result per distinct ID, this is why I need to have all rows with the same ID in the same partition.